# What is this letter?

Tags: notation

What is the highlighted letter and how do I pronounce it?
(When I copy and past it to a text editor, I came out as 'G')

[image: temporal order in cascade $C$ as $\mathcal{G}$, we call each diffusion tree a *diffusion scenario* $G \in \mathcal{G}$....]

I am currently studying an ICWSM 2018 paper: "DEBATENIGHT: The Role and Influence of Socialbots on Twitter During the First 2016 U.S. Presidential Debate"

An unknown character came out while I was reading section 3.1

Comment: Looks like a calligraphic G. I would call it "script G" for short. You have $G, \mathcal{G},\mathscr{G}$.

Comment: It's a script G. The latex command `\mathcal{G}` in an equation yields it: $\mathcal{G}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an uppercase in a script or calligraphic font.  It looks like the document was prepared with LaTeX, and in MathJax you can write `$\mathcal{G}$` to get $\mathcal{G}$.

Your excerpt is:

> temporal order as cascade $C \in \mathcal{G}$, we call each diffusion tree a *diffusion scenario* $G \in \mathcal{G}$.  Fig. 1a contains a cascade...